# How to explain the type of List.fold_left in Ocaml?

Tags: list, ocaml, fold

If you look at the type of List.fold_left in OCaml it gives the type ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a

I am not sure how to make sense of this fully, I can arrive at similar types but how do I get to the final type step by step?

Comment: Please post the implementation of the function you are looking at, and what type(s) you arrive at and how you did that.

Comment: I was just wondering how the OCaml compiler infers this type for the general case.

Comment: Yes, it does. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, the type ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a  is what the OCaml compiler gives, but I am wondering how it gets that type?

Comment: Note that you don't have to use alphabet letters for the type variables. I find that sometimes it helps. The type of `List.fold_left` can be written as: `('acc -> 'elt -> 'acc) -> 'acc -> 'elt list -> 'acc`.

Comment: @LucasNordmeyer How? [Hindley-Millner type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference), from looking how variables and parameters are used.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler uses a type inference algorithm that is based on a well-known [Hindley-Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) type inference algorithm.

The type is inferred from the implementation, e.g, this is a possible implementation of the `fold_left` function:

```
let rec fold_left f accu l =
  match l with
    [] -> accu
  | a::l -> fold_left f (f accu a) l
```

At the start, all values have most unrestricted types. We have three values here: `f`, `accu`, and `l`. So it assigns the to type variables `'a`, `'b`, and `'c`. A type variable `'a` basically means that a value can be of any type (totally unconstrained).

Then the typechecker goes throught a program (its AST representation) and collects facts about how each value is used. It uses a [syntactic unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) algorithm to unify all the facts. For example, it sees that `l` is matched to 
a list, so it now infers, that `l` is not just a value of any type `'c`, but is in fact constrained to be a `'d list`. Then the typechecker finds that value `f` is applied to `accu` and an element of a list (that has type `'d`). So it means, that `f` is not just a value of type `'a`, but a function of type `'b -> 'd -> 'b`. So, finally we have type: `('b -> 'd -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'd list -> 'b`, that then is re-normalized to `('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a`. I hope that you got a general idea, and details can be grabbed from the linked Wikipedia articles :)